# se muestra un numero repetido en el vector resultante

Tags: javascript

Hacer un algoritmo que forme un vector del que no se sabe el número de elementos. Calcule el promedio de los elementos y forme dos nuevos arreglos, uno con los elementos menores o iguales al promedio y otro con los superiores, Imprima los dos nuevos arreglos.en este código quiero crear del vector principal dos vectores que se guarde uno que sea menor al promedio y otro que sea mayor al promedio pero en el primer vector me sale el ultimo numero repetido 4 veces y quiero saber como solucionar este error.

```js
function five(){
        var arreglo=new Array();
        var valores="";
        var contador=0;
        var salida="salir";
        var suma=0;
        var promedio=0;
      // se crea el arreglo
        while(valores!=salida){
            valores=prompt("introduce el valor en la posicion "+contador);
            arreglo[contador]=valores;
             contador++;
    }

    arreglo.pop();
     contador=contador-1;

           //mostramos el array
          for(i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
            var text = document.createTextNode(arreglo[i] + "--") ;                                    
            document.getElementById("mostrar8").appendChild(text);

            suma=parseInt(suma)+parseInt(arreglo[i]);
            promedio=suma/contador;
         }
         
            var text = document.createTextNode("El promedio es  "+promedio) ;                                    
            document.getElementById("mostrar9").appendChild(text);

         // muestro los dos arreglos nuevos
         var arreglo2=new Array();
         var arreglo3=new Array()
            for(i=0; i<arreglo.length;i++){
               if(arreglo[i]<=promedio){
                   if(arreglo2[i]==arreglo[i]){
                       arreglo2.pop();
                   }else{
                       arreglo2=arreglo[i];
                   }
                   //var text = document.createTextNode("EL ARRAY 2  "+arreglo[i]) ;                                    
                     //document.getElementById("mostrar10").appendChild(text);
                //}else{
                  //  var text = document.createTextNode("EL ARRAY 3 "+arrelgo[i]) ;                                    
                    //document.getElementById("mostrar11").appendChild(text);
                    //alert("hola entro");
                }else{
                    arreglo3=arreglo[i];
                 }

                     var text = document.createTextNode(" "+arreglo2);                                    
                    document.getElementById("mostrar10").appendChild(text);

                    
                    var text = document.createTextNode(" "+arreglo3);                                    
                    document.getElementById("mostrar11").appendChild(text);

                

            }
               
}
```

```html
<p><strong>5 .</strong>
        Hacer un algoritmo que forme un vector del que no se sabe el número de elementos. Calcule el promedio de los elementos y forme dos 
        nuevos arreglos, uno con los elementos menores o iguales al promedio y otro con los superiores, Imprima los dos nuevos arreglos.
        <button  onclick="five();" >mostrar</button>
        <p id="mostrar8"></p>.
        <p id="mostrar9"></p>
        <p id="mostrar10"></p>
        <p id="mostrar11"></p>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que estas agregando contenido al documento dentro del for, osea que cada iteracion agrega los elementos del array 2 y 3 respectivamente, sacando esto del for, solo te los muestra una vez. Y para el array una forma de agregarle un valor es con .push().

```js
function five(){
        var arreglo=new Array();
        var valores="";
        var contador=0;
        var salida="salir";
        var suma=0;
        var promedio=0;
      // se crea el arreglo
        while(valores!=salida){
            valores=prompt("introduce el valor en la posicion "+contador);
            arreglo[contador]=valores;
             contador++;
    }

    arreglo.pop();
     contador=contador-1;

           //mostramos el array
          for(i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
            var text = document.createTextNode(arreglo[i] + "--") ;                                    
            document.getElementById("mostrar8").appendChild(text);

            suma=parseInt(suma)+parseInt(arreglo[i]);
            promedio=suma/contador;
         }
         
            var text = document.createTextNode("El promedio es  "+promedio) ;                                    
            document.getElementById("mostrar9").appendChild(text);

         // muestro los dos arreglos nuevos
         var arreglo2=new Array();
         var arreglo3=new Array()
            for(i=0; i<arreglo.length;i++){
               if(arreglo[i]<=promedio){
                   if(arreglo2[i]==arreglo[i]){
                       arreglo2.pop();
                   }else{
                       arreglo2.push(arreglo[i]);
                   }
                   //var text = document.createTextNode("EL ARRAY 2  "+arreglo[i]) ;                                    
                     //document.getElementById("mostrar10").appendChild(text);
                //}else{
                  //  var text = document.createTextNode("EL ARRAY 3 "+arrelgo[i]) ;                                    
                    //document.getElementById("mostrar11").appendChild(text);
                    //alert("hola entro");
                }else{
                    arreglo3.push(arreglo[i]);
                 }

            }

                     var text = document.createTextNode(" "+arreglo2);                                    
                    document.getElementById("mostrar10").appendChild(text);

                    
                    var text = document.createTextNode(" "+arreglo3);                                    
                    document.getElementById("mostrar11").appendChild(text);
               console.log(arreglo);
               console.log(arreglo2);
               console.log(arreglo3);

}
```

```html
<p><strong>5 .</strong>
        Hacer un algoritmo que forme un vector del que no se sabe el número de elementos. Calcule el promedio de los elementos y forme dos 
        nuevos arreglos, uno con los elementos menores o iguales al promedio y otro con los superiores, Imprima los dos nuevos arreglos.
        <button  onclick="five();" >mostrar</button>
        <p id="mostrar8"></p>.
        <p id="mostrar9"></p>
        <p id="mostrar10"></p>
        <p id="mostrar11"></p>.</p>
```

el nuevo array lo puedes mostrar mientras recorre el for o con un nuevo for a cada array

```js
function five(){
        var arreglo=new Array();
        var valores="";
        var contador=0;
        var salida="salir";
        var suma=0;
        var promedio=0;
      // se crea el arreglo
        while(valores!=salida){
            valores=prompt("introduce el valor en la posicion "+contador);
            arreglo[contador]=valores;
             contador++;
    }

    arreglo.pop();
     contador=contador-1;

           //mostramos el array
          for(i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
            var text = document.createTextNode(arreglo[i] + "--") ;                                    
            document.getElementById("mostrar8").appendChild(text);

            suma=parseInt(suma)+parseInt(arreglo[i]);
            promedio=suma/contador;
         }
         
            var text = document.createTextNode("El promedio es  "+promedio) ;                                    
            document.getElementById("mostrar9").appendChild(text);

         // muestro los dos arreglos nuevos
         var arreglo2=new Array();
         var arreglo3=new Array()
            for(i=0; i<arreglo.length;i++){
               if(arreglo[i]<=promedio){
                   if(arreglo2[i]==arreglo[i]){
                       arreglo2.pop();
                   }else{
                       arreglo2.push(arreglo[i]);

                     var text = document.createTextNode(" "+arreglo[i]);                                    
                    document.getElementById("mostrar10").appendChild(text);
                   }
                   //var text = document.createTextNode("EL ARRAY 2  "+arreglo[i]) ;                                    
                     //document.getElementById("mostrar10").appendChild(text);
                //}else{
                  //  var text = document.createTextNode("EL ARRAY 3 "+arrelgo[i]) ;                                    
                    //document.getElementById("mostrar11").appendChild(text);
                    //alert("hola entro");
                }else{
                    arreglo3.push(arreglo[i]);

                    
                    var text = document.createTextNode(" "+arreglo[i]);                                    
                    document.getElementById("mostrar11").appendChild(text);
                 }

            }

}
```

```html
<p><strong>5 .</strong>
        Hacer un algoritmo que forme un vector del que no se sabe el número de elementos. Calcule el promedio de los elementos y forme dos 
        nuevos arreglos, uno con los elementos menores o iguales al promedio y otro con los superiores, Imprima los dos nuevos arreglos.
        <button  onclick="five();" >mostrar</button>
        <p id="mostrar8"></p>.
        <p id="mostrar9"></p>
        <p id="mostrar10"></p>
        <p id="mostrar11"></p>.</p>
```